# iOS mixes up calls from different contacts with shared phone number

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

On my iPhone (iOS 12.1.4), I have several contacts who share the same workplace landline number (though each of them have their own extension numbers). After I call the workplace landline number of one of those contacts, on my phone's Recent Calls log, it shows the name of another contact with that same workplace number. How do I get my phone to display the correct contact name whom I actually called?